# Powershell - How to show only today files

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting, veeam

I am dealing with this little script, which shows me the latest data from a Veeam Software job.

```
$today = (get-date).Date
(Get-VBRBackup | where {$_.info.jobname -eq "A. ProduccionInterna.Infraestructura"}).GetAllStorages() | select {$_.PartialPath}, {$_.Stats.BackupSize/1GB}, {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today}
```

But it shows me all the existing results, not only those of the last day that would be the ones that interest me

Thanks for the help

Comment: You want to use a condition here before your final output. You need a `where {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today} ` condition. It ***is okay*** to chain `where` commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$today = (get-date).Date
$backup = Get-VBRBackup | where {$_.info.jobname -eq "A. ProduccionInterna.Infraestructura"}
if ($backup) {
    $backup.GetAllStorages() | where {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today} | select {$_.PartialPath}, {$_.Stats.BackupSize/1GB}
}
```

Comment: Show this: 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression'

Comment: It seems that there were no backups from the job in question today. Edited to handle such case.

Comment: I had a mistake. Hope fixed now :)

Comment: Now work!!! and now I can understand how it works !!! THANKS!!